# endMatchInTurnWithMatchData resulting in "The connection to service named com.apple.gamed was interrupted"

Tags: xcode, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

My call to endMatchInTurnWithMatchData is resulting in the connection to service interrupted error.  Any tips on what to look for to diagnose this problem?  Xcode 7.3.1, deployment target 9.3

```
-(void)sendGameOver {
    GKTurnBasedMatch *currentMatch = [[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper] currentMatch];

    // set the game outcome property for the current participant
    GKTurnBasedMatchOutcome otherOutcome;
    if (self.youAre == game.winningPlayer) {
        [currentMatch.currentParticipant setMatchOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon];
        otherOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;
    } else {
        [currentMatch.currentParticipant setMatchOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost];
        otherOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
    }

    // all other (only one other) participants get opposite outcome
    for (GKTurnBasedParticipant *nextParticipant in currentMatch.participants) {
        if (![nextParticipant isEqual:currentMatch.currentParticipant]) {
            [nextParticipant setMatchOutcome:otherOutcome];
        }
    }

    // prepare match data
    NSDictionary *turn = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[game]
                                                 forKeys:@[gameKey]];
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:turn];

    NSArray *achievements = [self achievementsToReport:currentMatch];
    NSArray *scores = [self scoresToReport:currentMatch];

    [currentMatch endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:data scores:scores achievements:achievements completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
            [self setGamePopUpMessage:@"Oops, there was a problem.  Try that again."];
        }
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the problem seems to be within the reporting of the achievements.  If I send an empty array for achievements, the error is gone.  But as soon as I attempt to pass achievement info with the endMatch, the error is back.

So I continue to receive the error "Connection to service named com.apple.gamed was interrupted" if I use

```
endMatchInTurnWithMatchData: scores: achievements: completionHandler:
```

However, if I use (as a workaround)

```
endMatchInTurnWithMatchData: completionHandler:
```

immediately followed by:

```
GKAchievement reportAchievements: withCompletionHandler:
```

then everything seems to work properly.

Comment: except that now I cannot report achievements for my opponent.  It is possible, in my game, for a player to make a  move which causes them to immediately lose.  In which case I want notch up one of my opponents achievements because they won.  But I get the error:

GKAchievement can only be submitted for another player when ending a turn-based match.

Which makes me think I need to go back to using:

        endMatchInTurnWithMatchData: scores; achievements: completionHandler:

Answer (score 0):

The original problem was that I was creating an array of achievements on my own, using GKAchievement initWithIdentifire in all cases, even for achievements that had already been reported for the player in previous matches.  The correct approach was to first call loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler to grab all the achievements that are already known for the player, then update the relevant ones.  If needed, a new GKAchievement can be added to that array.  But the key is to initialize the array properly.  Once I fixed all that, I was able to send the achievements array properly using endMatchInTurnWithMatchData: scores: achievements: completionHandler:and was no longer receiving my original error of 'connection service named com.apple.gamed was interrupted'.

HOWEVER...

My game is a two person game whereby it is possible for someone to be forced to take a turn (or to accidentally take a turn) causing them to immediately lose.  I wanted, in that case, to increment an achievement of their opponent (who just won).  It appears, however, that you cannot increment opponents achievements because you cannot know what their achievement level was before.

My work-around, which is not ideal, is that the player that lost the game on their turn reports any achievements that they might have gained (not any at the moment, but you never know....).  The winning player, whose turn it was NOT, will report their achievement upon receipt of the "matchEnded" message.  Unfortunately, this means that if they never open the game, they will not increment their achievement.  Not ideal.